# How to install Security Update patch APSB23-35

Tags: magento2, installation, security, patches, security-patch

is there any way to download the patch APSB23-35 and manually apply it ?
I have several older Magento2 installations, and update them is a time consuming task - so i was wondering if there is a "hotfix" so i can manyally deploy it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **Apply only the security patch in your current magento. please follow the below commands.**

**Before you start running the command please check whether your current magento version is affected or not.** : https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb23-35.html

> **For 2.4.6 and earlier**

**Affected Version: 2.4.6**

```
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p1 --no-update

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p1 --no-update

composer update magento/product-community-edition=2.4.6-p1 -w

composer update
```

> **For 2.4.5 and earlier**

**Affected Version: 2.4.5, 2.4.5-p1, 2.4.5-p2**

```
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p3 --no-update

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p3 --no-update

composer update magento/product-community-edition=2.4.5-p3 -w

composer update
```

> **For 2.4.4 and earlier**

**Affected Version: 2.4.4, 2.4.4-p1, 2.4.4-p2, 2.4.4-p3**

```
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4-p4 --no-update

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4-p4 --no-update

composer update magento/product-community-edition=2.4.2-p4 -w

composer update
```

Comment: Hi.. all 2.3.x versions seem affected and all version below 2.4.3-p1
Also, reading the documentation on composer, seems that the commands will update the Magento into the specified in "require"...or am i wrong?

Comment: No, this patch is not for 2.3.x version.  You can read about patch bby using this link : https://www.sparsh-technologies.com/blog/why-magento-patches-are-so-important-and-how-to-apply-them

Comment: for 2.3.x needs to be upgraded to their store 2.4.x Magento provides security patches for some versions only. for more please check this link: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/install-magento-2-security-patches.html

Comment: @ArmindoPereira I added the affected version name. Please check it and update your store.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do:

You can upgrade the Magento in a separate instance and check the updated code and then you are able to apply the custom patch in the code.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that will have thousands of files changed....i was looking for a .zip or .tgz or .patch so i can directly check the files.
A patch for the different versions

Comment: Have you contacted with the Magento Support

Comment: Not yet, since i'm using the open source version